# How to assign password to existing user to connect to SQL Server 2008 r2 from command prompt?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have converted mysql database to sql server using SSMA tool. Currently i can access SQL database from command prompt directly. I want to secure my database by assigning password to it. How can i do it from command prompt ?

Comment: You don't have to write with bold characters. We can read normal ones too. Thanks. [ALTER LOGIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Sqlcmd` with -P -U parameters in order to set password and username

Comment: thanks for your reply,C:\Users\D3-Devils>sqlcmd -p root -u KEEP-GOING i tried this line but i got this error(Sqlcmd: 'KEEP-GOING': Unexpected argument).

Comment: Actually it's `-P`, for password, and `-U`, for username. The `-p` and `-u` are valid parameters too but they mean something very different. @AnshulPatel: You can always run `sqlcmd -?` to get a quick summary of all available parameter options.

Comment: @AndriyM. Tanks for your comment.